# Show PDF cover page as thumbnail on browser

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, plugins

My requirement is that i have to display list of PDF documents on browser as rectangular boxes. In the rectangular box i need to show PDF document cover page as thumbnail. When user clicks on any rectangular box, calls goes to server side and document will download on client.

We have couple of JQuery plugins that works as PDF viewer but what i need is PDF first page as thumbnail.

**My questions is can we achieve this on client side?**

If not then i will have to possibly work this out on server side by converting PDF page to image using JPedal/Ghost4J tools and then sending images to client side.

Comment: You should do this server side. I guess theoretically it could be done client side, but it'd mean you'd have to send every single PDF to the browser (possibly 1mb+ per PDF) just to generate the thumbnail.

Comment: I understand the performance bottleneck if we have to make so many calls on page load. I was thinking to ease page load time using lazy-loading. Say i have to show only 5 documents thumbnail on page load, how can i do the same on client side. I am very much interested to know how we can achieve this on client side ?

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js should get you started I guess. This is a project that'll render PDFs using javascript, but it'll need some tweaking.